# VS code Hidden folder permission denied

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, salesforce, permission-denied, sfdx

[image]Visual Studio code is not able to open files or folder within hidden folders. If I go to the file within the hidden folder .sfdx and try opening the file sfdx-config.json then Vs code opens with below error
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"blr-ffefe","pid":21322,"log":"Login","level":50,"msg":"[\n  'ERROR running auth:web:login: ',\n  "EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/usernname/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json'"\n]","time":"2022-04-07T08:58:22.413Z","v":0}

I have also removed all the files.exclude , this is happening in Mac OS Monterey.

Steps to reproduce :
Mac OS Monterey

navigate the hidden folder
right click on any file within the hidden folder and select open with Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can solve this problem by creating a hidden folder
(with .) and a hidden file using the VS Code itself. By using file -> Open -> create any hidden folder/file in the open window.